# Use the alternative form of the derivative to find the derivative at $x=c$ if $f(x)=x^3+4x, \ c=2$

Tags: derivatives

Use the alternative form of the derivative to find the derivative at $x=c$ if $f(x)=x^3+4x$ and $c=2$.

I keep getting stuck with the answer being $0$, no matter how I try to solve it. 
If someone could please use step-by-step instructions to help me see what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: What do you understand by "the alternative form of the derivative"? This is not standard terminology.

Comment: @AlexM. I'd guess he means $\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sources online I can only interpret the 'alternative' form as this:

$$
f^{\prime}(x) = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$

So,

$$
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(2) &= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3 + 4x - (2^3 + 4 \cdot 2))}{x - 2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3 + 4x - 16}{x - 2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 8)}{x-2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 2} \, (x^2 + 2x + 8)\\
&= 16
\end{align}
$$

The important step is cancelling the $x-2$ in the denominator, notice we can do this because $x-2\neq 0$ as we are considering the limit. Can you see which point you were struggling at?

Comment: Yes I factored it our incorrectly. Thank you so much, 16 is what my graph was giving me as the answer so I appreciate your help! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I meant *out